# CakePHP - check for foreign key integrity on dataload

Tags: postgresql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I currently have a system which required regular data imports. The db is Postgresql.

What I want to do is validate if a foreign key does not exist on a dataload.

For example

Customer belongs to Title and the 'titles' table contains 
( id : name )
1 : Mr
2 : Mrs
3 : Miss

If during the dataload I pass in say 22 as a title_id, postgres throws a foreign key constraint violation which throws a php warning. Does anyone know of a way to catch this rather me having to write custom validation rules?

Thanks

Leo

Comment: have you tried `dependent => true` in your model?

Comment: .I haven't Ross, that option relates to recursive deletion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using PDO, you can set the error mode to throw exceptions, like such:

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

You can then catch the exception and do whatever you please with it.